# Polymer 1.0 iron-media-query call function on query-changed

Tags: polymer-1.0

I don't really understand why the following code isn't working. I want iron-media-query to call a function when the query changes. I got it working using query-matches and template if's but that isn't what I want at all. Here is the code I have:

```html
<iron-media-query 
            query="(max-width:1024px)"
            query-matches="{{condensedscreen}}"
            query-changed="switchToCondensed">
        </iron-media-query>
```

I want the query-change="switchToCondensed" to be called once this query requirement is met. 
The switchedToCondensed function is the following:

```js
switchToCondensed: function(e) {
            console.log("Condensed: "+this.condensedscreen);
            if(this.condensedscreen === true) {
                this.sectionbox = "section-boxes-condensed";
                this.setScreenSize = "checkoutBodyMobile";
                //this.sectionStyle = "sectionMobile";
                this.shippingSectionStyle = "shippingSectionMobile";
                this.allCardsStyle = "allCardsMobile";
                this.submitBtnStyle = "submitBtnMobile";
                this.gotocartStyle = "goToCartMobile";
            }
            else {
                this.sectionbox = "section-boxes";
                this.setScreenSize = "checkoutBody";
                //this.sectionStyle = "section";
                this.shippingSectionStyle = "shippingSection";
                this.allCardsStyle = "allCards";
                this.submitBtnStyle = "submitBtn";
                this.gotocartStyle = "goToCart";
            }
        }
```

As you can see I want to use this to change around the CSS on my webpage. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use "on-query-matches-changed" instead of "query-changed"?

```
<iron-media-query 
            query="(max-width:1024px)"
            query-matches="{{condensedscreen}}"
            on-query-matches-changed="switchToCondensed">
        </iron-media-query>
```

Comment: This works! Unfortunately, this only works one way with my code so I will have to rethink how I code this up to use on-query-matches-changed.

Answer (score 3):

So I never got query-changed to work. Honestly that seems completely useless. Anyway, I got it to work by first adding the $ to my class like the following:

```js
<div class$="[[allCardsStyle]]">
```

After that I removed the query-changed from iron-media-query so it looked like the following:

```html
<iron-media-query 
            query="(max-width:1024px)"
            query-matches="{{condensedscreen}}">
        </iron-media-query>
```

Then back in the JS I added an observer to watch when the boolean variable changes:

```js
condensedscreen:{observer:"switchToCondensed"}
```

Finally, with that watching the change I had it call my function "switchToCondensed" that actually set the variable to mobile vs not:

```js
switchToCondensed: function() {
        if(this.condensedscreen === true) {
            this.allCardsStyle = "allCardsMobile";
        }
        else {
            this.allCardsStyle = "allCards";
        }
    }
```

Then in my CSS I have two different styles that are call allCards and allCardsMobile.
Hopefully this helps someone that was struggling with this like me.